# C++ unordered map requiring copy constructor when adding my custom hash function

Tags: c++, hash, c++17, copy-constructor, unordered-map

I am trying to use a custom hash struct for class `A` which is a key type in an `std::unordered_map` which is one of `std::variant` alternatives in class `B`.
Here is a simplified version of my code where the error can be reproduced:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <variant>

namespace myNamespace {
    class A;
    struct AHasher;
    class B;

    // ....

    class A {
        public:
            A(const std::string& str);
            friend bool operator==(const A& lhs, const A& rhs);
        public:
            std::string value;
    };

    struct AHasher {
        std::size_t operator()(const A& str) const;
    };

    class B {
        public:
            B();
            B(const std::string& str);
            B(const A& str);
            B(const std::initializer_list<std::pair<const A, B>> list);
        private:
            std::variant<A, std::unordered_map<A, B, AHasher>> value;
    };

}  // namespace myNamespace 

// .......

namespace myNamespace {
    A::A(const std::string& str) : value(str) {}
    bool operator==(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) { 
        return lhs.value == rhs.value;
    }

    std::size_t AHasher::operator()(const A& str) const {
        std::hash<std::string> hasher;
        return hasher(str.value);
    }
   
    B::B() : value(std::unordered_map<A, B, AHasher>{}) {}
    B::B(const std::string& str) : value(A(str)) {}
    B::B(const A& str) : value(str) {}
    B::B(const std::initializer_list<std::pair<const A, B>> list) : value(list) {}

} // namespace myNamespace 


int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling with GCC 9.4.0 with command:  `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 main.cpp`
Compilation is failing with the following message:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:40,
                 from tmp.cpp:53:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘struct std::pair<const myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B>’:
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/aligned_buffer.h:91:28:   required from ‘struct __gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer<std::pair<const myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B> >’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:233:43:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hash_node_value_base<std::pair<const myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B> >’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:264:12:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B>, true>’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable_policy.h:2027:13:   required from ‘struct std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B>, true> > >’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/hashtable.h:173:11:   required from ‘class std::_Hashtable<myNamespace::A, std::pair<const myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B>, std::allocator<std::pair<const myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<myNamespace::A>, myNamespace::AHasher, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, false, true> >’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unordered_map.h:105:18:   [ skipping 2 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:901:12:   required from ‘struct std::__is_copy_constructible_impl<std::unordered_map<myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B, myNamespace::AHasher>, true>’
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:907:12:   required from ‘struct std::is_copy_constructible<std::unordered_map<myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B, myNamespace::AHasher> >’
/usr/include/c++/9/type_traits:2918:25:   required from ‘constexpr const bool std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::unordered_map<myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B, myNamespace::AHasher> >’
/usr/include/c++/9/variant:275:5:   required from ‘constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<myNamespace::A, std::unordered_map<myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B, myNamespace::AHasher, std::equal_to<myNamespace::A>, std::allocator<std::pair<const myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B> > > >::_S_copy_ctor’
/usr/include/c++/9/variant:1228:11:   required from ‘class std::variant<myNamespace::A, std::unordered_map<myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B, myNamespace::AHasher, std::equal_to<myNamespace::A>, std::allocator<std::pair<const myNamespace::A, myNamespace::B> > > >’
tmp.cpp:81:64:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:215:11: error: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second’ has incomplete type
  215 |       _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
      |           ^~~~~~
tmp.cpp:74:11: note: forward declaration of ‘class myNamespace::B’
   74 |     class B {
      |           ^
```

Why am I getting messages about copy consturctors here? It is my understanding that the compiler will generate default copy and move constructors if I do not explicitly make my own

Before using this implementation, instead of `std::unordered_map` I was using an `std::map` with the appropriate operator overloads in class `A` and everything worked fine

Comment: fyi looks like something was fixed in gcc 12.1 this fails to compile in 11.3 - live https://godbolt.org/z/1o9sGf9cK .  Compiles ok in clang and MSVC.

Comment: Using gcc 9.3, it looks like you could simplify your [mre] quite a bit: `#include <unordered_map>  class B { std::unordered_map<int, B> value; };

int main() { return 0; }` -- the fewer irrelevant details to parse, the easier it is to understand the problem.

Comment: @JaMiT `return 0;` is also an irrelevant and unnecessary detail....

Comment: @TonyDelroy *"`return 0;` is also an irrelevant and unnecessary detail"* -- True. That's why I did not (or at least intended not to) claim that I simplified as much as possible. ;) I intentionally kept the `main` function as it is in the question as a reference point. *Because if I removed the `return` statement, someone would fixate on that change, and thereby overlook the changes to the class definitions. Hopefully that seems unbelievable, but between the things I've seen here and my own luck, I'd give it a 90+% chance.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mention of a copy constructor is a red herring. The error occurs while generating one of the copy constructors, but the error has nothing to do with copy constructors:

> error: ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second’ has incomplete type

The error is an incomplete type. Your `B` contains a `std::unordered_map` that itself contains `B`. The definition of `B` is not complete until its closing brace; as such `B`, when the unordered map is declared is incomplete, it's a forward declaration.

There were variations in various revisions of the C++ standard regarding which containers can be defined with an incomplete class for the containers' values, and it only needs to be defined when it's actually used. That's a separate issue, but insofar as your question as to what a copy constructor has to do with any of this, the answer is that it doesn't.